# Caching API's data which is associated with user session using Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, amazon-elasticache

How to cache an API's response in a user session using Redis.
So that for each other user the information will be depends on the user session I'd.

Answer (score 0):

You should craft the SessionId in such a way that it uses a valid set of characters for a Redis key.

Then you choose a prefix, *sess* for example, and you concatenate that with the session id.

```js
const redisKey = `sess_${session_id}`

redisClient.get(redisKey, (err, reply) => {
  console.log(reply)
})
```

Also, don't forget to set/update the TTL (time to live) to your key when you set its value so it disappears after a while without any user interaction and you avoid overflowing your Redis server capacity.